# VBA Outlook Text not added to email body

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

My working code will browse to all incoming emails moved to a specified folder. Once it's in the folder, macro will run to check if that email is existing in my Excel History File.

The code below is working in such a way that it returns me the value of the Agent's name. However, it doesnt append that agent's name in the email. Is this code correct for adding text in email body :

```
emlBody = ActiveAgnt & vbCrLf & emlBody
```

If yes, then why does the Agent's name added in the email body? Below is the rest of the code.

```
Set objFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("For Processing")
Set objItems = objFolder.Items

For Each obj In objItems
        For lgCurrentRow = 2 To lgLastRow
            If obj.Class = olMail Then
                strSubj = myXLApp.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lgCurrentRow, "C")
                StrSR = myXLApp.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lgCurrentRow, "D")
                StrAgnt = myXLApp.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lgCurrentRow, "E")
                emlSubj = obj.Subject
                emlBody = obj.Body

            '>>>>>Check if incoming email has an existing SR in History File<<<<<
                If emlSubj Like "*" & strSubj & "*" Then
                    Debug.Print strSubj
                    '*****If existing then check if there is an existing SR
                    '*****Append to email if SR is existing
                    If StrSR <> "" Then
                        Debug.Print StrSR
                    '*****If SR is not existing check if an agent is tagged to the email.
                    '*****If agent is tagged then append agent's name to email
                    ElseIf StrAgnt <> "" Then
                        Debug.Print StrAgnt
                    End If
                    Exit For
            '^^^^^Check if incoming email has an existing SR in History File^^^^^

            '>>>>>If Incoming file is not match Check Active Agents list to assign Agent<<<<<
                 ElseIf emlSubj <> "*" & strSubj & "*" Then
                        Call ActiveAgents(ActiveAgnt)
                        Debug.Print ActiveAgnt
                        emlBody = ActiveAgnt & vbCrLf & emlBody
            '^^^^^If Incoming file is not match Check Active Agents list to assign Agent^^^^^

                Exit For
                            Set obj = Nothing
                            Set objItems = Nothing
                            Set objFolder = Nothing
                            Set objOL = Nothing
                            Set obj.Body = Nothing
                End If

            End If

        Next

    Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
emlBody = ActiveAgnt & vbCrLf & emlBody
```

try

```
obj.Body = ActiveAgnt & vbCrLf & obj.Body
```

Comment: Thanks. However it only works for the selected email and not for the rest of the email in the folder.

Comment: What you are saying then is your question was successfully answered.

Comment: It seems like you need an `obj.Save` in there to deal with all the non-active ones.

Comment: @niton Partially Yes. It appends the text in the body. However, it doesnt append for the other emails. @Doug Clancy the `obj.Save` solves the rest of the problem. Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that worked which incorporated @niton and @Doug Glancy suggestions.

```
ElseIf emlSubj <> "*" & strSubj & "*" Then
                    Call ActiveAgents(ActiveAgnt)
                    Debug.Print ActiveAgnt
                    obj.Body = ActiveAgnt & vbCrLf & obj.Body
                    obj.Save
```